# gwan and mongodb

Tags: c, mongodb, g-wan

I am new to gwan and currently coding a simple program to insert and select data from MongoDB.
After I compile the Mongo-c-driver, and put the Mongo standard library in /usr/lib/, I find that my program under gwan/csp folder has an error:

```
Linking myprog.c: undefined symbol: mongo_client
```

My program

```
#include <mongo.h>
int main(){ 
    ...
    mongo conn[1];
    int status = mongo_client( conn, "192.168.1.115", 27017 );
}
```

(The program I coded under a Linux environment works!) <- I mean the mongodb official testing code.

```
gcc -o output -lmongoc myprog_Linux.c
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: You should check #pragma include “[path]” or #pragma link “[path]modulename[.ext]” as described in the documentation

Comment: I had tried #pragma include and #pragma link, but still dont work...

Comment: Finally, problem were solved since I have include the header file !!
Thanks !!!!

Comment: @moriya: since you solved your own problem, you can post your answer below so that others can learn from the solution :).

Comment: I forget to include the header file after "#pragma include" and "#pragma link" , after I add the header "#include "mongo.h" , problem solved!!

Comment: He means use the "Post Your Answer" form at the end of the page, and then mark it as the answer. Don't post the solution in comments since people might miss it :)

Comment: @Stennie I just added a sample in the answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a little sample for gwan + mongoDB

First : Install the mongoDB c driver (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver.git
$ cd mongo-c-driver
$ scons
$ sudo scons install
```

It will install in /usr/local folder, you'll need to adapt it if needed or just copy generated files into /usr/lib & /usr/include/

then run ldconfig as root

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Once the mongodb c driver is installed, just try with this simple sample :

```
// ============================================================================
// C servlet sample for the G-WAN Web Application Server (http://trustleap.ch/)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// mongodb.c: querying mongoDB from G-WAM
// ============================================================================

#pragma link "mongoc"
#pragma link "bson"

#include <mongo.h>
#include <bson.h>
#include "gwan.h" // G-WAN exported functions

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);
   mongo conn[1];
   int status = mongo_client( conn, "localhost", 27017 );

  if( status != MONGO_OK ) {
    switch ( conn->err ) {
      case MONGO_CONN_NO_SOCKET:  printf( "no socket\n" ); return 1;
      case MONGO_CONN_FAIL:       printf( "connection failed\n" ); return 1;
      case MONGO_CONN_NOT_MASTER: printf( "not master\n" ); return 1;
    }
  }

  int i = 0;
  for(i=0; i<100;i++) {
    bson b[1];
    bson_init( b );
    bson_append_new_oid( b, "_id" );
    bson_append_string( b, "name", "Joe" );
    bson_append_int( b, "age", 33 );
    bson_finish( b );
    mongo_insert( conn, "tutorial.people", b, NULL );
    bson_destroy( b );
  }

  xbuf_xcat(reply, "Hello Mongo !! %d %d", status, i);

  return 200;
}
// ============================================================================
// End of Source Code
// ============================================================================
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using third-party libraries from G-WAN scripts then you must use the `#pragma include "library_include_path"` and `#pragma link "library_name"` directives (they replace a makefile).

Of course, as usual with C/C++, the #include  header must be used to add the definitions used by a library.

This is documented in the [G-WAN PDF manual](http://gwan.com/archives/gwan_linux.pdf), in the [developers](http://gwan.com/developers#libraries) website, the [G-WAN FAQs](http://gwan.com/faq#use_libraries), and in many servlet examples relying on various libraries (libcurl, libmysql, libsqlite,  libcairo, libmagick, etc.).